# How do I make HTML light boxes on my merchandise page that show details specific to each product?

Tags: javascript, html, codepen

I am coding a website for a school project and decided to add a merchandise page. I wanted to include a product view so that people can see more details (like a description) when they click on a product.

I initially used this idea from a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/curnsey/pen/LGgvoL) I found and it works really well but the only problem is it brings up the same lightbox no matter what product you click on. I want a design that is product specific. I tried simply adding more light boxes but it didn't change anything. I think this has something to do with the Javascript but I am not sure as I have not learned the basics of that language yet.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="lightbox-blanket">
    <div class="pop-up-container">
      <div class="pop-up-container-vertical">
        <div class="pop-up-wrapper">
          <div class="go-back" onclick="GoBack();"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="product-left">
              <div class="product-info">
                <div class="product-manufacturer">NOOK
                </div>
                <div class="product-title">
                  LOUNGE CHAIR
                </div>
                <div class="product-price" price-data="320.03">
                  $320<span class="product-price-cents">03</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-right">
              <div class="product-description">
                Designer Karim Rashid continues to put his signature spin on all genres of design through various collaborations with top-notch companies. Another one to add to the win column is his work with Italian manufacturer Chateau d’Ax.
              </div>
              <div class="product-available">
                In stock. <span class="product-extended"><a href="#">Buy Extended Warranty</a></span>
              </div>
              <div class="product-rating">
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" star-data="1"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" star-data="2"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" star-data="3"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star" star-data="4"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star" star-data="5"></i>
                <div class="product-rating-details">(3.1 - <span class="rating-count">1203</span> reviews)
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="product-quantity">
                <label for="product-quantity-input" class="product-quantity-label">Quantity</label>
                <div class="product-quantity-subtract">
                  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" id="product-quantity-input" placeholder="0" value="0" />
                </div>
                <div class="product-quantity-add">
                  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-bottom">
              <div class="product-checkout">
                Total Price
                <div class="product-checkout-total">
                  <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
                  <div class="product-checkout-total-amount">
                    0.00
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-checkout-actions">
                <a class="add-to-cart" href="#" onclick="AddToCart(event);">Add to Cart</a>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="random-background">
    <div class="itemlist">
      <div class="itemlist-item-wrapper" onclick="OpenProduct(1);">
        <div class="product-details">
          <div class="">
            <div class="product-info">

              <div class="product-title" item-data="1">
                LOUNGE CHAIR
              </div>
              <div class="product-price" price-data="320.03" item-data="1">
                $320<span class="product-price-cents">03</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-image" item-data="1">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemlist-item-wrapper" onclick="OpenProduct(2);">
        <div class="product-details">
          <div class="">
            <div class="product-info">

              <div class="product-title" item-data="2">
                LOUNGE CHAIR
              </div>
              <div class="product-price" price-data="320.03" item-data="2">
                $320<span class="product-price-cents">03</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-image" item-data="2">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemlist-item-wrapper" onclick="OpenProduct(3);">
        <div class="product-details">
          <div class="">
            <div class="product-info">

              <div class="product-title" item-data="3">
                LOUNGE CHAIR
              </div>
              <div class="product-price" price-data="320.03" item-data="3">
                $320<span class="product-price-cents">03</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-image" item-data="3">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemlist-item-wrapper" onclick="OpenProduct(4);">
        <div class="product-details">
          <div class="">
            <div class="product-info">
              <div class="product-title" item-data="4">
                LOUNGE CHAIR
              </div>
              <div class="product-price" price-data="320.03" item-data="4">
                $320<span class="product-price-cents">03</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-image" item-data="4">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemlist-item-wrapper" onclick="OpenProduct(5);">
        <div class="product-details">
          <div class="">
            <div class="product-info">
              <div class="product-title" item-data="5">
                LOUNGE CHAIR
              </div>
              <div class="product-price" price-data="169.49" item-data="5">
                $<span class="product-price-dollar">169</span><span class="product-price-cents">49</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-image" item-data="5">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And Javascript:

```
//Go Back
function OpenProduct(i){
  var i = $('.product-image[item-data="'+i+'"] img');
  var lbi = $('.lightbox-blanket .product-image img');
  console.log($(i).attr("src"));
  $(lbi).attr("src", $(i).attr("src"));  
  $(".lightbox-blanket").toggle();
    
  $("#product-quantity-input").val("0");
  CalcPrice (0);
  
}
function GoBack(){
  $(".lightbox-blanket").toggle();
}

//Calculate new total when the quantity changes.
function CalcPrice (qty){
  var price = $(".product-price").attr("price-data");
  var total = parseFloat((price * qty)).toFixed(2);
  $(".product-checkout-total-amount").text(total);
}

//Reduce quantity by 1 if clicked
$(document).on("click", ".product-quantity-subtract", function(e){
  var value = $("#product-quantity-input").val();
  //console.log(value);
  var newValue = parseInt(value) - 1;
  if(newValue < 0) newValue=0;
  $("#product-quantity-input").val(newValue);
  CalcPrice(newValue);
});

//Increase quantity by 1 if clicked
$(document).on("click", ".product-quantity-add", function(e){
  var value = $("#product-quantity-input").val();
  //console.log(value);
  var newValue = parseInt(value) + 1;
  $("#product-quantity-input").val(newValue);
  CalcPrice(newValue);
});

$(document).on("blur", "#product-quantity-input", function(e){
  var value = $("#product-quantity-input").val();
  //console.log(value);
  CalcPrice(value);
});


function AddToCart(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var qty = $("#product-quantity-input").val();
  if(qty === '0'){return;}
  var toast = '<div class="toast toast-success">Added '+ qty +' to cart.</div>';  
  $("body").append(toast);
  setTimeout(function(){ 
  $(".toast").addClass("toast-transition");
    }, 100);
  setTimeout(function(){      
    $(".toast").remove();
  }, 3500);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a workaround of your code as it seems incomplete. You said *problem is it brings up the same lightbox no matter what product you click on*, but you uses a ```jquery``` which your header(<script>) import is not included in your code.

Comment: More details about the issue please